# Is there a web app to create ASCII art tables?

Tags: webapp-rec

Is there a web app that can create ASCII-art tables like this one?:

```
------------------------------------------------
|           | ColA            | ColB           |
------------------------------------------------
| Row1      | CellA1          | CellB1         |
------------------------------------------------
| Row2      | CellA2          | CellB2         |
------------------------------------------------
| Row3      | CellA3          | CellB3         |
------------------------------------------------
```

It doesn't have to use ASCII (it can be Unicode), I meant ASCII in the sense of [ASCII art](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII_art).

This would be useful for sites that don't support proper tables (like Stack Exchange).

Comment: Please check this one:
http://www.softpedia.com/get/Office-tools/Other-Office-Tools/ASCII-Art-Table.shtml Regards

Comment: [Create ASCII art tables](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/43498/3579), [Software to draw shapes in plain text file (ASCII/Unicode)](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/3916/3579)

Answer (score 81, accepted):

Now there is: [Format Text as Table](https://senseful.github.io/text-table/).

I've been meaning to create this utility for a while. I was actually inspired by MySQL's command line utility and the lack of tables on SO. So thanks for reminding me to make it.

And thanks to @Lipis for the Unicode char idea.

Here's an example of the output:

```
+------+--------+--------+
|      | ColA   | ColB   |
+------+--------+--------+
| Row1 | CellA1 | CellB1 |
| Row2 | CellA2 | CellB2 |
| Row3 | CellA3 | CellB3 |
+------+--------+--------+
```

Comment: I don't always want to fire up Excel to put in a table.  Would you consider allowing other delimiters (comma, 2+ spaces, semicolon...) to be used in your utility?

Comment: this is excellent! referenced at http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96125/how-to-format-sql-tables-in-stack-overflow

Comment: @KevinVermeer: I made it so that you can type the tab character in the edit box. Does that solve the problem, or do you still want other delimiters?

Comment: I really like this tool, but it has problems dealing with blank/empty cells from excel

Comment: Unfortunately, it's broken as of this writing and can only generate html. It's been broken for a little over a month.

Comment: @EdwardFalk: I just fixed it and updated the link!

Comment: Indeed, nicely done

Comment: The github link goes to a 404 now -- hopefully this gets fixed soon, as all the comments are very positive!

Comment: @MeghanArmes no need to click the github link. The tool is available on the linked page directly: https://senseful.github.io/web-tools/text-table/

Comment: @Senseful beautiful -- thank you!

Comment: Thanks for the great tool - however I just tested it and you can't directly copy/paste it into a SO question/answer since they require `4 spaces` before inputting code, so I had to chuck it into my editor first, indent it and then paste it into SO - not a huge deal, but perhaps you could include an ability to auto-indent (such as a checkbox selection?). Thanks!

Comment: The link has changed again. It's now: https://senseful.github.io/text-table/

Comment: @Brett you can highlight the text on SO, then choose to format as code and it'll indent by 4 spaces. I'll try to add a checkbox to auto indent by 4 spaces when I have time.

Comment: @Senseful Gotta admit I feel pretty stupid now lol; always disregarded that button for some reason.

Answer (score 23):

The following utility (created by me) may come in handy for such scenarios : http://plaintexttools.github.io/plain-text-table/

[image: screenshot]

Usage is fairly simple and intuitive, thanks to the spreadsheet like editing capabilities of [handsontable](http://handsontable.com) . Also it handles multi-line cells neatly.

Comment: Looks very nice. I would add a screenshot to make it stand out more !!

Comment: @JacobJanTuinstra Thanks for the feedback. Updated the answer as per your suggestions.

Comment: This one is superb. I'll be bookmarking this one.

Answer (score 9):

While not especially for tables, [Asciiflow](http://www.asciiflow.com/)  is a generic tool for this kind of thing.

Answer (score 4):

Since the OP specifically says:

> It doesn't have to use ASCII (it can be Unicode)

I thought I'd share the link for the **[(mysql / unicode / html) table generator](http://www.sensefulsolutions.com/2010/10/format-text-as-table.html)** created by a [SE user](https://superuser.com/users/14797/senseful) for use on SE I found on [superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/482688/what-tools-exist-for-generating-ascii-tables-if-any). I found it quite useful to get unicode tables (which I sometimes prefer over the Windows-1252 compatible "ASCII" art). And this tool lets you compare the outputs, as well as getting a HTML formatted table, too.

**Example to show my workflow:**
I'm making a web app for my bookkeeper to calculate sales tax and I am doing math on months and quarters so that the tool always automatically displays *"last quarter's sales tax info"*. Since  I'm always thinking of arrays starting with 0, I needed to embed a simple table outlining the months in each quarter to keep the values sorted in my head.

**1)** To get the table started, I used **[this generator](http://lorefnon.me/plain-text-table/)** (listed on both this and the other QA) with its Excel-like input interface to actually create the data, as the unicode tool wants pre-formatted text. I type in the values then select them and <kbd>CTRL-C</kbd> to get my tab delimited table:

```
Quarter Numbers Names
Q1  1, 2, 3 Jan, Feb, Mar
Q2  4, 5, 6 Apr, May, Jun
Q3  7, 8, 9 Jul, Aug, Sep
Q4  10, 11, 12  Oct, Nov, Dec
```

**2)** went to **[senseful's generator](http://www.sensefulsolutions.com/2010/10/format-text-as-table.html)** and pasted into the input area. I played with each of the 3 options and I liked the Unicode Art option the best:

```
╔═════════╦════════════╦═══════════════╗
║ Quarter ║  Numbers   ║     Names     ║
╠═════════╬════════════╬═══════════════╣
║ Q1      ║ 1, 2, 3    ║ Jan, Feb, Mar ║
║ Q2      ║ 4, 5, 6    ║ Apr, May, Jun ║
║ Q3      ║ 7, 8, 9    ║ Jul, Aug, Sep ║
║ Q4      ║ 10, 11, 12 ║ Oct, Nov, Dec ║
╚═════════╩════════════╩═══════════════╝
```

Note that for the table to show up correctly on a web page, the character set must be specifically set for UTF-8:

`<meta content='text/html; charset=UTF-8' http-equiv='Content-Type'/>`

Comment: You know that the accepted answer is the tool you suggest and it is posted by the author you mention, right ? :)

Comment: yes... between this and another answer, I wanted to show my workflow, since either by themselves didn't help my situation and would have required transcribing the whole table. Together, I didn't need to type all that info in by hand.

Comment: I have updated http://lorefnon.me/plain-text-table/ You can now directly generate the desired Unicode Art output (see the style option `Double Border`)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this tool for mysql tables:
[MySQL Table to text](http://scriptun.com/mysql/table-to-text-coverter)